# WIth django, can you do something similiar to user = User.new(params[:user]) during a form post?

Tags: python, django

in ruby/ror you can do this:

```
user = User.new(params[:user])
```

which populates a new object with the values from a posted form.

Can something similar be done using django/python?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [model form documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). Basically, the code would look like:

```
f = UserForm(request.POST or None)
user = f.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Django's built-in auth app, then keep in mind that there are a few considerations when creating users, such as passwords, unique usernames, etc

Comment: yes, in rails you can explicitly state which properties you allow to be mapped, or state which properties to ignore.